# java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=... }

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have some errors only on a few devices when using Speech Recognizer as follows. It looks like it conflicts with the other services provided by other apps/systems on the device but not exactly sure it is and how to avoid it. Could anybody elaborate on it?

Brand: `Google Cros` / Model: `AMD Stoney Ridge Chromebook` / OS: `Android 9`

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=org.chromium.arc.applauncher/.input.service.ArcVoiceInteractionService }
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1677)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1612)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:698)
       at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(SpeechRecognizer.java:287)
```

Brand: `Oppo` / Model: `Find X2 Pro` / OS: `Android 11`

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=com.arlosoft.macrodroid/.voiceservice.MacroDroidVoiceService }
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1893)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1804)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:766)
       at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(SpeechRecognizer.java:287)
```

Brand: `Amazon` / Model: `Kfmuwi` / OS: `Android 9`

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=amazon.speech.sim/com.amazon.alexa.multimodal.assistant.AlexaVoiceInteractionService }
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1721)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1656)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:698)
       at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(SpeechRecognizer.java:287)
```

The app implementation is like:

```kotlin
internal class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    //...
) {
    private val speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplication())

    private fun startSpeechRecognition() {
        val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        intent.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
        )
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault().toString())
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true) 
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 10000)

        try {
            speechRecognizer.startListening(intent)
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            // Here I get the errors I mentioned
        }
    }
}
```